# Does Emmet's name imply that he is a golem?

Tags: mythology, the-lego-movie

The protagonist of The Lego Movie (2014) is named **Emmet Brickowski**. Like most of the other characters in the film, Emmet is a Lego figure but seems to be able to move independently, [or so we are led to think](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134216/do-the-minifigures-have-any-control-of-their-actions-within-the-lego-world).

Emmet/Emmett is of course [a real-world name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Brown) but in many versions of the story of the golem ([including the Polish one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem#Earliest_stories)) "emet" or "emeth" (אמת, "truth" in Hebrew) is also the word written in or on a clay figure to animate it. I always assumed this was an in-joke, especially given that Brickowski, while a fictional surname and obviously a Lego joke, [has a Polish structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_name#Suffix_-ski.2F-ska).

**Is there any evidence that this was an intentional reference to the golem myth on behalf of the creators?**

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question to make it (a little) clearer what you're asking. Also, I know you (really) love brackets, but they're not (always) necessary.

Comment: [Not a very original question](https://community.lego.com/t5/LEGO-General/The-Significance-of-the-Name-Emmet/td-p/8690006)

Comment: @mat-cauthon Not *completely* original from the look of it (and as I noted in an earlier edit, I spotted after posting that someone on TV Tropes also made the Emmet/Emet connection), but I notice nobody actually answered my question adequately in your link either.

Comment: As did I. Just wanted to point out there are such discussions already. Doesn't seem fruitful.

Comment: @mat-cauthon this isn't meant to disparage the factfinding ability of the Lego forums crowd in any way, but I've seen the community here manage some pretty astonishing things. I'm happy to give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

IMDB has a trivia note that says:

> ["Emmet"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emmet) is an archaic word for "ant", an insect well known for being a construction worker that works in a team. - [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/trivia?item=tr2938955)

To me, that explanation sounds more plausible than Emmet is a golem. Emmet the worker ant means he is just one cog in the very large wheel of Bricksburg.

Comment: It's an archaic word for ant **in [Old-Cornish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmet_(Cornish))**. Unless you can connect one of the writers with the speaking an *ancient dialect of an obscure British sub-language*, I see no reason why this should be the more likely option.

Comment: @Valorum: no, it's also dialectal English, as the link says. "Ant" is in fact a contraction of the same word as "emmet".

Comment: Emmet is slang for tourist in Cornish.

Comment: Either way, is there any reason that they'd choose this word? Emmet also means "sausage" in Slovenian and "Puppet" in Cantonese.

Comment: Emmet[t] was a very common german first name that was pervasive in upstate NY into the Midwest (see "Northern Cities Vowel Shift" for the region) from late 19th century through early 20th century. (regionally more common than national graphs might suggest). I have several relatives with this name going back generations.